# Linking unit test executable against pybind library (CMake)

Tags: python, c++, cmake, pybind11

I'm using pybind11 and CMake to build python bindings for a set of C++ libraries. I would like to have C++ as well as Python unit tests for the bindings. The issue is that the target created by CMake using `pybind11_module_add` cannot be linked against from my unit test executable:

```
target_link_libraries(my_bindings_lib_test
  PRIVATE
    my_bindings_lib # <- target of type MODULE_LIBRARY may not be linked into another target
    gtest
}
```

Now there are a few alternative solutions I'm considering, each with certain drawbacks:

- Use `pybind_module_add(target SHARED ...)` to generate a shared library. The drawback is having to modify the source code to export all the symbols.
- Include all the bindings library source code files in the test CMake and effectively build them twice.
- Use `add_library` instead of `pybind_module_add` and do all the Python related stuff (finding and linking Python, NumPy, generating library suffix etc.) manually.

Perhaps there are some others I'm missing. What would be preferable approach?

Comment: You probably mean [pybind11_add_module](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/compiling.html#pybind11-add-module) function, not a `pybind11_module_add` and not a `pybind_module_add`.

Comment: Have you checked [Partitioning code over multiple extension modules](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/misc.html#partitioning-code-over-multiple-extension-modules) in the pybind documentation? It describes how to write dependent pybind modules.